# How to cancel export?

Tags: shell

I am installing the RISCVde tool chain. I find that I always miss the installation.

When I output echo $RISCV, it points to an empty directory. I see it is defined in the /etc/profile file:

```
export RISCV=/opt/riscv-toolchain
export PATH=$RISCV/bin:$PATH
```

How can I cancel it?

Comment: You can "delete" an environment variable with `unset VARIABLENAME`, in example: `unset RISCV`. Or you may just remove your mentioned 2 `export` lines from `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unset RISCV` or `env -i bash`.

`env --help`:

```
-i, --ignore-environment  start with an empty environment
```